# Can Changesets Be Tampered With in TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I've been experiencing some situations where I feel as though what is present in a changeset of mine isn't always representative of what I did.

Example: I incremented a version number in AssemblyInfo.cs through the project properties GUI and in a couple other locations. I then checked in my changes and moved on deploying things.

Come to find out, the AssemblyInfo.cs file had been emptied. I checked on my disk and the file contained binary of all zeros.

This is the most recent event in a series of headscratchingly frustrating changeset issues.

Is it possible for someone to tamper with a changeset without leaving any audit trail, or is it possible that the GUI in Visual Studio is corrupting certain things on me?

Comment: I would suggest checking the hardware on all the machines involved as that sort of thing could well be something more low level.

Comment: @EnergyWasRaw, is the AssemblyInfo.cs file on your local machine empty or the checked AssemblyInfo.cs file shows empty? How about you choose to get latest version for that file?

Answer (score 0):

When you check in your changes, they are stored on the server as a changeset. Changesets contain the history of each item in version control.

You can view a changeset to get information about:

•which files were changed

•what the exact changes were

•who changed the files

•what the check-in comment contains

•which work items are associated with the changeset

•which policy warnings appeared

TFS won't tamper changesets if you have a successful checkin. You can try on another client machine to see whether your issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to make changes to TFS version controlled files without  leaving any audit trail by anyone or GUI.

You are able to check the file's history via right clicking the file in the Source Control Explorer and click "View History". From the listed changesets, you are able to check who submitted the changeset on which date. If you don't want any one specific changeset, you can just [rollback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194956.aspx) it.